# "You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits."

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I got the notification:

> An edit was suggested to your post [Drupal 7, Fedora - dd() doesn't work for me over the web](https://superuser.com/questions/605456/drupal-7-fedora-dd-doesnt-work-for-me-over-the-web), please review it.

"Review it" is a [link](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/128695) that allows me to review the edit.  At least in theory it does.  When I clicked "Next", I got the message in the subject line.

Why am I getting a notification asking me to do an action that I'm not allowed to do?

Comment: Yeah, that's a bug—you should always be able to review edits on your own posts.

Comment: 'Next' is the only button that doesn't make sense here, as it skips this post and continues reviewing other stuff. But yeah, it shouldn't even be shown...

Comment: The `Next` button appears only if the a review is already completed. Otherwise there is a `Skip` button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your case, it's working correctly in our test environment. The author of the post can either approve or reject suggested edits.

[image: before review]

After the edit is either approved or rejected you see this notification, which is slightly different from what you suggested.

[image: after review]

What happened is that the suggested edit was rejected before you could approve / reject it. Thus the "Next" button is the only option you have.

[image: reviewed]

But since you do not have enough rep to continue reviewing, you've received the error notification shown in the 2nd picture.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I'm assuming there's some simple way to streamline the programming logic.  Cheers!